# X velocity in Unity2D c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C# and Unity. I need to normalize the velocity of my player, but only in the x-direction. My current code is

```
void Update ()
{
if(rb2d.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = rb2d.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
    }
```

This controls all velocity. I tried

```
void Update ()
{
if(rb2d.velocity.x.magnitude > maxSpeed)
    {
        rb2d.velocity.x = rb2d.velocity.x.normalized * maxSpeed;
    }
```

But I think this was removed in Unity 5. What can I do?

Comment: i don't know much about unity, but i do know maths. You can normalize a vector by dividing the x and y components by the length of the vector

Comment: I tried that, but that's not really the issue, mainly because the max speed is the issue. But thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just divide your velocity X by the velocity's magnitude, which is essentially what normalize does.

```
// Make a copy of the current velocity.
Vector2 velocity = rb2d.velocity;

// Divide the x component by magnitude, equivalent to normalizing it.
velocity.x = velocity.x / velocity.magnitude;

// velocity now only has its x component normalized and y untouched
rb2d.velocity = velocity * maxSpeed;
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how I can implement this. I put that in the if statement. and it's saying XVelocity doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: @Zanolon well, `XVelocity` doesn't exist in this answer either, so it's clearly something you added.